# CSS wrap "up" so first line is shortest?

Tags: css

I want to show a list of tags at the bottom of the screen and if they don't all fit, I want it to wrap so that it's the first line that is the shortest - not the last line.

Once the bottom line is full, I would prefer if the next item added would be what would then appear *above* instead of below. But if it's easier to make the first item move up that would be ok too.

This example should make it clear:

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: right;
}

span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7B68EE;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Apple</span>
  <span>Orange</span>
  <span>Banana</span>
  <span>Pear</span>
  <span>Apricot</span>
  <span>Cranberry</span>
  <span>Blackcurrant</span>
  <span>Raspberry</span>
  <span>Strawberry</span>
  <span>Plum</span>
  <span>Tomato</span>
  <span>Lemon</span>
  <span>Lime</span>
  <span>Coconut</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding flexbox styles to the parent container like so:

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: right;
  /* flexbox styles */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7B68EE;
  /* margin to separate tags */
  margin: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Apple</span>
  <span>Orange</span>
  <span>Banana</span>
  <span>Pear</span>
  <span>Apricot</span>
  <span>Cranberry</span>
  <span>Blackcurrant</span>
  <span>Raspberry</span>
  <span>Strawberry</span>
  <span>Plum</span>
  <span>Tomato</span>
  <span>Lemon</span>
  <span>Lime</span>
  <span>Coconut</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I marked this answer best because of `justify-content: flex-end;`, although all answers were valuable!

Comment: Thanks @JasonWood — I've updated with `margin` for each tag based on your other comments.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `display:flex`, also use `flex-wrap:wrap-reverse` in order to wrap the elements the way you want.

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: right;
}
        
span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7B68EE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using flex property to align like this,

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; // reverse the wrapping
  flex-direction: row-reverse; // reverse the row
}
```

also add some margin to span

```
span{
  margin:3px;
}
```

> **[flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)** - The flex-wrap CSS property sets whether flex items are forced onto one line or can wrap onto multiple lines. If wrapping is allowed, it sets the direction that lines are stacked.

> **[flex-direction: row-reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)** - Work in a `left-to-right` language such as **English**. If you are working in a **right-to-left** language like **Arabic** then row would start on the right, row-reverse on the left.

**Result:-**

[image]

**LIVE DEMO**

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7B68EE;
  margin:3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Apple</span>
  <span>Orange</span>
  <span>Banana</span>
  <span>Pear</span>
  <span>Apricot</span>
  <span>Cranberry</span>
  <span>Blackcurrant</span>
  <span>Raspberry</span>
  <span>Strawberry</span>
  <span>Plum</span>
  <span>Tomato</span>
  <span>Lemon</span>
  <span>Lime</span>
  <span>Coconut</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer add anything materially different than the existing answers?

Comment: Indeed... adding the margin was necessary as everything was jammed together after adding flexbox. Also reduced padding. `flex-direction: row-reverse;` did not give me what I want, however. `justify-content: flex-end;` from another answer did exactly what I wanted. Thank you!